# How to access nested JSON with ReactJS?

Tags: json, reactjs

So I have this JSON provided by a Drupal backend, and I'm trying to access the different fields in it. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, because the console is not outputting any errors, but I still can't get the title in the fornt-end, or any other fields.

```
var Magazine = React.createClass({
    loadMagazinesFromServer: function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: true,
        success: function(data) {
          this.setState({data: data});
          console.log(data);
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
          console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
      });
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {data: []};
    },


    componentDidMount: function() {
      this.loadMagazinesFromServer();
    },

    render: function () {
      return (
        <div> Magazine title: {this.state.data.title} </div>
      );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render( <Magazine  url='http://landliebe.lo/all-magazines/hal_json' /> , document.getElementById('content') );
```

And here is the JSON that I get.

```
[
    {
        "nid": [
            {
                "value": "2"
            }
        ],
        "title": [
            {
                "value": "Praesent venenatis metus"
            }
        ],
        "uid": [
            {
                "target_id": "1",
                "url": "/user/1"
            }
        ],
        "body": [
            {
                "value": "<p>Morbi mattis ullamcorper velit.. Donec interdum, metus et hendrerit aliquet, dolor diam sagittis ligula, eget egestas libero turpis vel mi. Praesent ut ligula non mi varius sagittis. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Praesent turpis. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Vestibulum facilisis, purus nec pulvinar iaculis, ligula mi congue nunc, vitae euismod ligula urna in dolor. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Vivamus in erat ut urna cursus vestibulum. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Vivamus consectetuer hendrerit lacus. Mauris turpis nunc, blandit et, volutpat molestie, porta ut, ligula. Nulla sit amet est.</p>\r\n",
                "format": "basic_html",
                "summary": ""
            }
        ],
        "field_image": [
            {
                "target_id": "3",
                "alt": "",
                "title": "",
                "width": "2211",
                "height": "1382",
                "url": "http://landliebe.lo/sites/default/files/magazines/covers/London.jpg"
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "nid": [
            {
                "value": "1"
            }
        ],
        "title": [
            {
                "value": "Phasellus accumsan"
            }
        ],
        "uid": [
            {
                "target_id": "1",
                "url": "/user/1"
            }
        ],
        "body": [
            {
                "value": "<p>Phasellus volutpat, metus eget egestas mollis, lacus lacus blandit dui, id egestas quam mauris ut lacus. Sed libero. Cras varius. Vivamus laoreet. Cras varius.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna dolor sagittis lacus. Sed magna purus, fermentum eu, tincidunt eu, varius ut, felis. Praesent adipiscing. Proin viverra, ligula sit amet ultrices semper, ligula arcu tristique sapien, a accumsan nisi mauris ac eros. Pellentesque auctor neque nec urna.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Nulla sit amet est. Curabitur turpis. Morbi mattis ullamcorper velit. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris.</p>\r\n",
                "format": "basic_html",
                "summary": ""
            }
        ],
        "field_image": [
            {
                "target_id": "2",
                "alt": "",
                "title": "",
                "width": "2457",
                "height": "1382",
                "url": "http://landliebe.lo/sites/default/files/magazines/covers/Facet%201.jpg"
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

Can someone please help me :( ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get `title` from your `data`, but your data is an array and doesn't have `title` property. I guess, you need to display a list of magazines, you can do it like that:

```
var MagazineList = React.createClass({
    loadMagazinesFromServer: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: true,
            success: function(data) {
                this.setState({data: data});
                console.log(data);
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: []};
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.loadMagazinesFromServer();
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
               {
                   // map all array element to React elements
                   this.state.data.map(magazine => (
                       <Magazine {...magazine} />
                   ))
               }
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Magazine = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div> Magazine title: {this.props.title} </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render( <MagazineList url='http://landliebe.lo/all-magazines/hal_json' /> , document.getElementById('content') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Download react dev tools for chrome and you'll then be able to inspect the props your are passing to your component. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

I'm guessing here as I can't see your react components in your example, but it is possible your could be passing the title property as an array.

Comment: That's all the code there is.  there is just another index.html where I have the <div id="content"></div> which I populate with react.